# Does binding two WPF controls to one model property create a shared binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Why is it that if I bind two controls, say 2 TextBoxes, to a single property of a model which does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged the content of two text boxes stay in sync?  How is the other TextBox being notified of the other one updating the source?

Model:

```
namespace BindingExample
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingExample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PersonModel x:Key="person"></local:PersonModel>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        </Style>    
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource person}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? I would have said that this is expected behaviour, but you say you haven't implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` - in which case I wouldn't expect either `TextBox` to update.

Comment: @ChrisF expect initially, when the binding simply reads the value of the source property.

Comment: @Jason Sich is the source property perhaps a DependencyProperty, although that would be strange in a model class.

Comment: @ChrisF I updated with a simple model and view.  So my question is why do both textboxes stay in sync with each other?

Comment: Jason - I don't know - I do Silverlight development rather than WPF and the way Bindings are handled is one of the differences between the two. Anything I say would come from that perspective and might well be wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two textboxes in your example are using the same datacontext and actually share the same instance of the .NET object PersonModel, since the default setting of the static resource in the resource dictionary WPF is *shared*, i.e. when referencing to the static resource you will always get the same instance. More about the the x:Shared attribute on MSDN:

[MSDN article about x:Shared attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)

An alternative to this is to set x:Shared to false to get a new instance everytime. In addition, I had to remove the binding to the datacontext in your example to individually be able to edit the values in the textboxes indivually.

The following XAML shows this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfScrollToEndBehavior.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfScrollToEndBehavior"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PersonModel x:Key="person" x:Shared="false" Name="John Doe"> </local:PersonModel>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource person}}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource person}}" />
</Grid>
```

The reason for x:Shared is set to true for resources in a resource dictionary is for efficiency reasons. By setting x:Shared on a resource (e.g. an object) in a resource dictionary in XAML will give us new instances everytime the resource is references and accessed. I had to remove the data context from the grid and set the source of the binding for the textboxes to the static resource person.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm learning WPF as I go, and from what I knew this behavior seemed wrong at first.

Comment: The answer "because to textboxes share same datacontext object" doesn’t explain why two TextBoxes are in sync.

It would be the answer if PersonModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But it is not the case.

The process looks like this:

- say textbox1.Text changed by user.
- It bounded to the PersonModel.Name so it updates the property.

But how on earth textbox2.Text gets to know about this new value of the Name property? The PersonModel object doesn’t notify about changes in its properties.